# Having troubles using Valgrind with WSL on CLion

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, clion, valgrind

Working on Windows 10, enabled WSL and installed Ubuntu.
WSL toolchain configured, I can build and run stuff on CLion, everything works perfectly except for Valgrind.

I used the path:

```
\\wsl$\Ubuntu\usr\bin\valgrind
```

but everytime I try to run a Memcheck I get:

```
Valgrind executable is not found
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Jetbrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/memory-profiling-with-valgrind.html#). Just skip the wsl/ubuntu part. Clion will automatically check the wsl system configured at your toolchain. Your configuration should look like this:

[image: My configuration]